# Error in reading array list from beans

Tags: jakarta-ee

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Seating {

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void readExcelFile(String fileName) {
    List cellData = new ArrayList();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        XSSFWorkbook xwb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = xwb.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow xrow = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
            Iterator iterator = xrow.cellIterator();
            List cellTempList = new ArrayList();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell xcell = (XSSFCell) iterator.next();
                cellTempList.add(xcell);
            }
            cellData.add(cellTempList);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    process(cellData);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void process(List cellData) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cellData.size(); i++) {
        List cellTempList = (List) cellData.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < cellTempList.size(); j++) {
            XSSFCell xCell = (XSSFCell) cellTempList.get(j);
            String stringCellValue = xCell.toString();
            System.out.print(stringCellValue + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "C:" + File.separator + "Documents and Settings"
            + File.separator + "a492161" + File.separator + "Desktop"
            + File.separator + "FIMTArea.xlsx";
    new SeatReconcile().readExcelFile(fileName);
}
```

}

Seat.htm

Seat.jsp

<%
    String file=request.getParameter("text1");
    String cont = SeatingBean.process(file);

```
out.println(cont);
```

%>

Type mismatch error pls check and solve this

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in the Seat.jsp:

```
SeatingBean.process(file);
```

should be

```
SeatingBean.readExcelFile(file);
```

Then readExcelFile(...) should also return a String value with the results of the Excel file. But an other solution would be to return the List and Iterate over the list in the jsp page. E.g.,

```
public List readExcelFile(String fileName) {
   ...

   return cellData;
}
```

and in Seat.jsp

```
<%
    String file = request.getParameter("text1");
    List cellData = SeatingBean.readExcelFile(file);
    Iterator i = cellData.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
%>
<%= ""+i.next() %><br/>
<%
    }

%>
```

Comment: <% SeatingBean.readExcelFile(fileName); %>                         I have given this code but still the result is same which says fileName cannot be resolved.

Comment: Shouldn't this be file instead of fileName? See additional comments above.